# Will Silverlight reduce my web traffic?

Tags: silverlight

I want to develop a web application in Silverlight.
Can this reduce my web traffic and if so, how much ?

Comment: I suggest you read this (slashdot.org) http://developers.slashdot.org/story/10/10/29/2147238/Microsofts-Silverlight-Strategy-Has-Shifted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it really depends on who your target audience is.
If your users would want to access your site using a smartphone, they won't be able with Silverlight.
If a significant portion of your audience uses Linux they may not be able to access your site.

If your site is interesting enough and your customers don't fall into the two previous categories, they will install the plug-in if they haven't already.

However, don't forget the crawlers from search engines cannot read inside a Sillverlight application. If you want to be referenced by them, you might have to use some artifices like "hiding" bot-readable text behind your Silverlight application.
Silverlight itself may not decrease your traffic (depending on your audience), but a bad referencing sure can hurt you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the last PDC, there are rumors that Microsoft itself thinks, that HTML5/JavaScript is main technology for web applications and Silverlight is for those who need something very complex, that is to hard to implement using HTML5. Also Silverlight is great choice for intranet apps inside corporate networks etc. 
BTW, Silverlight is not available on iOS devices like iPad and this is very significant problem, because such devices are growing on the market. I believe that it will not be available on iOS in nearest future.

Comment: No need to be Apple-centric here: there's also no Silverlight for Blackberry, Android, or WebOS, either.

Comment: Again I would say for business applications used mainly on the computer Silverlight is the way to go. I am a one person developer (two are joining now) and I have cranked out stuff very quickly with Silverlight. There is no way to replicate that in another development environment currently.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for information such as http://www.riastats.com/. This will show you general statistics of what most browsers carry on a per browser/operating system basis. (Ironically, 100% of their clientele will have flash installed ;p)

Microsoft will grossly over-estimate the number of users with Silverlight and can handle the application, so not advisable to just go to their website (it's probably based on statistics taken over their inTRAnet. But I would be you have a fair portion of the market with it and, assuming you have good content and a great site, people will download whatever is necessary to view it.

As another user posted, Silverlight is powerful in the workplace. It offer invaluable tools for connecting network and deploying tools to users without the need to install (or they can run Out-of-Browser and it will update every time they open it, automatically [Very handy for IT people who hate deploying new software])

Comment: Yes, ironically, when I go to riastats.com I just see "Alternate HTML content should be placed here. This content requires the Adobe Flash Player. Get Flash", half covered by a google ad.  :-)

Comment: @Ken: I stand corrected, 100% of their clientele _*must*_ have Flash installed (at least to view the numbers. :grin:

Answer (score 1):

Adobe claims that 99% of computers [have Flash installed](http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/flashplayer/).  I'm not sure of the numbers for Silverlight, but I would imagine it's much lower.

One problem with Flash/Silverlight is that it's harder for Google to index than HTML.

Unfortunately, HTML5 will not be a cross-browser solution until IE9 comes out, and even then, there will be a lot of people using IE7 and IE8 who won't be able to view your app.

I like Silverlight a lot, but I would say that yes, it would reduce your web traffic compared to a JavaScript app or a Flash app.

Answer (score 0):

From a personal standpoint, I like Silverlight. I think it looks clean, sharp, I like the functionality and versatility it offers.

But from a usability standpoint, looking at the answer by @Mace, I agree that if it's not available across the growing platforms that would definitely be something to take into account.

The site that both @theChrisKent and @Brad Christie shared is great for attaining the above-desired information about the platform info.

But, again, if it were me, I would go for it just for the cleanness and functionality Silverlight brings to the table.  Yes, it *can* reduce your web traffic, but how much would just depend on what your clientele look like as far as their platform is concerned.

Comment: I agree, Silverlight is clean and pristine it allows you to take existing .NET code and outfit it from ASP and the caveats of working int he HTML space, to a polished application. You just have to ask yourself who the intended audience is, and do you care if Google finds it.

Comment: @Brad Christie - amen to that, that's definitely true.